# Nginx rewrite rules not working

Tags: apache-http-server, php, nginx, htaccess, rewrite

We are moving our site from Apache to Nginx. So far, the rules that we have converted from .htaccess rules to nginx are working fine but this particular rule is giving me a hard time.

I've tried online converters which use if (Which I don't use) and manually tried to convert the rules but nothing is working. If someone can guide me in the right direction or point where I'm going wrong, it will be of great help.

Apache .htaccess rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+).html$ /products/code_asset_2019.php?page=$1&filename=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*\.php)$ /products/code.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /products/code.php?page=$1

</IfModule>
```

Directory structure:
`root   /var/www/html`;

inside

```
/html
```

, we have `/products` folder which contains **code_asset_2019.php** and **code.php**

My converted rules which are not working:

```
location /products {
      try_files $uri $uri/ @rules;
    }

    location @rules {
    rewrite ^/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)\.html$ /products/code_asset_2019.php?page=$1&filename=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/(.)/(.\.php)$ /products/code.php?page=$1;
    rewrite ^/(.*)\.html$ /products/code.php?page=$1;

    return 404;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put this instead of everything you have:

```
rewrite ^/products/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)\.html$ /products/code_asset_2019.php?page=$1&filename=$2 last;
rewrite ^/products/(.)/(.\.php)$ /products/code.php?page=$1;
rewrite ^/products/(.*)\.html$ /products/code.php?page=$1;
```

Comment: It's an hour past midnight here and I was about to sleep but just give me 5 minutes, I'm trying this out right now. This issue has been keeping me awake  anyway.

Comment: Danila, you've no idea how thankful I'm to you for your help. This worked. Can you please elaborate a little why the previous rules didn't work?

Comment: @Axel, I think because in your Apache config `RewriteRule ^(`, matches to `/products` because `.htaccess` was inside the directory, whereas in nginx, the match will always check against full URL. So your example needs `rewrite ^/products(...` instead of `rewrite ^/(`. But I have simplified things further: if you need to rewrite a bunch of URLs, you don't need `location` stuff at all.

Comment: Nice! I get it now. Thank you!
If you don't mind, I've one more question.
When I was working in Apache, We had a php file which would form questions based on guid of the questions and if the question bank had more than one question, the  url would look like:
`www.mywebsite.com/file.php&group_guid=001,001hG,001IF,001Mp,001Qf,001QH,001Qk,001qk,001tq,0022Q`
Guid of the questions were separated by comma but in nginx, this is not working. First question would display fine but other questions will not and it will display a Page Not Found 404 error.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my last comment?